# Change the Chat link's href to be more specific

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, top-bar

I posted this question [over at Meta Aviation](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36/update-the-link-to-chat):

> Currently, this link goes to `http://chat.stackexchange.com`:
>
> [image]
>
> Can it be updated to
>   `http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/aviation`?

Somebody replied saying it can't be changed. Is that right?

If so, my feature request is: can the Chat link be made editable to mods?

Otherwise, is there anyone who can change it?

Comment: I don't think that the chat link should cause a user to directly join a room.

Comment: @TravisJ On Aviation's chat link, you're given a list of *all* sites within the network to choose from; which doesn't make sense. Mathematica's chat link is exactly the same as Aviation's, but when clicked only shows Mathematica related rooms.

Comment: Perhaps it could link to the transcript of that room. `http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/12036`

Comment: @TravisJ Transcripts can be downright painful to read, and probably aren't the most enticing thing to show someone brave enough to click that link :)

Comment: @TinyTim - Haha, that is true. Some rooms tend to be a little NSFW at times.

Comment: If I click the link on Aviation (not registered on the site), I am only shown that room: http://i.3ventic.eu/20131218172419291.png

Comment: @3ventic Who changed something?! Now it's working, lmao!

Answer (score 3):

This is problematic because while many rooms stay as they are for what seems like an indefinite amount of time, they're hardly static things that we'd want to use as navigation links. You might rename the room once (or if) the community decides on something different.

Additionally, 'chat' right now takes people to a gallery of rooms created around that particular site. By taking someone right to the general room, they might miss out on rooms dedicated to chatting about helicopters, single engine planes, etc. It's better to give folks the choice.

What we *do* show is a cached snapshot participation in the active rooms in some places on the side bar, which we hope entices people to go check it out.

As long as you've got a few people in your room *most* of the time, folks are likely to find it and join if they're at all interested in chatting - I wouldn't worry about it too much, if that's a concern.

Comment: It seems the issue was either that `chat.stackexchange.com` hadn't been updated to include Aviation's room, or there was an issue with authentication whilst changing domains. Until a minute ago, clicking the Chat link was displaying the entire list of rooms.

Comment: Additionally, http://chat.aviation.stackexchange.com still shows all sites network-wide, rather than Aviation-specific rooms, when redirected to `chat.stackexchange.com`. Shouldn't it be redirecting to `http://chat.stackexchange.com/?host=aviation.stackexchange.com` behind-the-scenes, like the Chat link in the top bar is now doing?

Comment: @DannyBeckett I'm going to set a note to check that again once private beta finishes, a few things are odd during this phase, and this might be one of them.